# How to change the Hostname for my Windows XP OS?

Tags: windows-xp

Windows XP OS

Recently i have formatted my Computer and Installed few programming Softwares like Visual Studio / SQL 2008.

My hostname or Servername is the default name provided by Windows OS Installation ..!

I want to change the default name to "Former".

How to change the Server / HostName of my Computer?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Properties for My Computer and select the Computer Name tab, then click the Change button.

Comment: On doing so, whether this is affect my Software installed on my Computer ? I have installed SQL 2008 - by mapping to Windows Authentication .. So servername will be detected as Default Server Name ..!

Comment: That I couldn't say for certain, but Windows generally works by UUIDs and not names for that kind of thing.